# Unexpected Results using NOT IN ()

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble understanding this and have looked at the suggested duplicates but when I examined a bunch of other queries I can figured out why there is such a big discrepancy between the following.

Why does: Total Results - IN (X, Y, Z)

Not equal: NOT IN (X, Y, Z)

I've even checked a more basic query such as:

```
 SELECT PT.personId, PT.tagId, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.Deleted 
 FROM persontags as PT 
 LEFT JOIN person as P 
 ON P.PersonId = PT.personId 
 WHERE PT.CreatedBy = '21' 
       AND PT.tagId != '4765' 
       AND P.Deleted != 1 
 GROUP BY P.PersonId
```

So Total Results with no filters/conditions are: 4546

Using IN (4765) to get matching records which have that tagId = 44

So why is NOT IN (4765) producing 3940 results instead of 4542?

Comment: Perhaps you have some `NULL` tag Ids? they would fail both `IN` and `NOT IN` tests

Comment: Perhaps 562 records have tagId = NULL?